# WCF Restful service IIS Error

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, wcf-rest

i have made a service and deployed on somee.com and im getting the handler error. 
http://rssfeed.somee.com/RSSFeed.svc
I am not really sure what is causing the problem or what am i missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to enable WCF/http activation on your server.

On server 2012, it's under server manager -> roles and features -> features -> .net framework 4.5 features -> wcf services -> http activation

On windows 7/8: programs and features -> Turn windows services on or off -> .NET Framework Advanced services -> WCF -> Http activation.

Try that, run iis reset and refresh your service

Specifically for somee.com, to use svc extensions in wcf services;

> If your WCF service has an extension .svc you need to add a Managed
>   handler for that extension in your Web.Config file.
>
> Web.Config Handler configuration examples:

v3

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name=".svc" verb="*" path="*.svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

v4

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
         <add name=".svc" verb="*" path="*.svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Source: http://somee.com/doka/DoHelpTopics.aspx?docode=false&thnid=113

Comment: its running perfectly on my local system, the problem occurring is when i am uploading it to server

Comment: my IIS is configured correctly ive added the mime types and activated the wcf http activation, the problem is on the hosted server

Comment: WCF / http activation is enabled on the hosted server aswell?

Comment: How to check that? actually I am using `somee.com` to host my service, and I did not find any such option there in control panel.

Comment: I updated my post, did you check that you have registered the handler in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above I would also check your mapping for the web service in your web.config file.

And the configuration of the type of binding you are using.For example

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" name="folder1.folder2.service">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
           contract="folder1.folder.Iservice" />
      </service>
```

and then a definition of your binding as well with the configuration you need.